# Xcode Instruments Error: Failed to attach the target process. Unable to instantiate loader for target

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I always get this error when I try to use Profile in Instruments.
I tried to find some solution and I can't solve it.
I appreciate any help.
I'm using MacBook Pro M1 and Xcode 12.5.1.

Thanks

[Instruments Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJhQ2.png)

Comment: I'm facing this error in Xcode 14.3.1. Have you found any solution?